# I am in Rails 2.3.8, can I use Acivesupport 3.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activesupport

I am trying to use the phony gem, and it says I need activesupport 3?

But I am on rails 2.3.9.

Can I just add the activesupport gem in bundler to make it work?

If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly doubt that will work. There have been *many many* changes to Rails 3, and it's sometimes difficult to even port a Rails 2.x app to Rails 3.